# Fantasy Manga about Main Character playing a building game

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character plays a building game, he builds a city for years, and on that city there is a tower that he first built in that city. Then he got teleported into that city game, then he had a power to make anything from his hand, what title is that?

I read it online, but I don't remember what site I used, it's a Japanese manga. The setting is about a fantasy city, with human and demi human or beast, after the main character gets teleported, he just get in the jail. When he's hungry and thinks about bread then there is just pop up a bread in front of him, what title is that manga?

Answer (score 6):

**["*Hakoniwa Oukoku no Craft Master*"](https://myanimelist.net/manga/110481/Hakoniwa_Oukoku_no_Craft_Master) by Nanamomo Rio.**

Also called: *Craftmaster of Miniature Garden Kingdom*, *Creator-sama of the Little Garden Kingdom Craft* and *Hakoniwa Oukoku no Souzoushu-sama*.

> An Otaku programmer who spent the last three years creating the world he desires on the computer suddenly encounters a BUG. He gets depressed and sleeps. When he wakes up, he finds himself in his own world with crafting power.

The first thing he built was indeed a watchtower, the rest matches as well.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I've edited in where I believe you got the quote from (as it's identical), in the future if you are quoting from a source can you provide attribution from the source and also use quotation markdown i.e. start the line with `>`.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot : Bull's eye ^^ Thanks for the edit, I'll keep the markdowns you used in mind !